# How to change the Frame / Position of the Tab bar in Xamarin forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am new to be Xamarin Forms and C#.
Now I want to implement the Tabbar in my Xamarin Forms App.

For this I used the following Code

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Project.Views.DummyPage111">

    <TabbedPage.Children>

        <ContentPage Title="Tab 1">
            <Label Text="Page 1" />
        </ContentPage>

        <ContentPage Title="Tab 2">
            <Label Text="Page 2" />
        </ContentPage>

        <ContentPage Title="Tab 3">
            <Label Text="Page 3" />
        </ContentPage>

        <ContentPage Title="Tab 4">
            <Label Text="Page 4" />
        </ContentPage>
    </TabbedPage.Children>

</TabbedPage>
```

It is working fine in both Android & iOS, But I need to maintained the tab-bar position in top of the screen in iOS & Android.
So for this I need to move the tab-bar to top position in my app.

I need to customise the tab-bar position.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this [Set Tabbar position to Top for iOS in Xamarin.Forms](https://github.com/acastr7/CustomTabbedPageRendererSample)

Make custom renderer for Tabbed page in iOS and it will place the tabbar on top position

Hope this may solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you, but this project is not running in Mac mini in both Android & iOS.

Comment: I have tried this sample solution and its working fine for me, you can try it out the renderer of iOS in your project and it may solve your issue!

Comment: it is running in Windows System and launched tab bar in Android. But while I try to running on my Mac Mini it is not running in iOS and as well as it is not launching the iOS app.

Comment: This link is now dead. Do you have a new link?

Comment: @Kyle You can try below links, if it works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741361/remove-white-space-at-the-bottom-when-moving-tabs-to-the-top-in-xamarin-ios/45748990#45748990

Comment: @Kyle refer this discussion https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/101652/toptabbedpage-a-xamarin-forms-control-for-tabs-at-top-on-ios

Comment: Let me know if any of above works, will update my answer with that code.